# PayPal Pro iframe integration

Tags: iframe, paypal, integration

Hi I am trying to build IFRAME based PayPal integration.

```
$api_endpoint = "https://payflowpro.paypal.com";
$secureTokenId = uniqid('',true);
$postData = "USER=".$api_username."&VENDOR=".$api_vendor."&PARTNER=".$api_partner."&PWD=".$api_paswd."&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=".$secureTokenId.
                        "&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=12.00";
```

that is coming back with SUCCESS

string(101)

```
"RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=Rk3gglURw6kecY50rNk9DbQO5&SECURETOKENID=53c5406db58374.69023239&RESPMSG=Approved" array(4) { ["RESULT"]=> string(1) "0" ["SECURETOKEN"]=> string(25) "Rk3gglURw6kecY50rNk9DbQO5" ["SECURETOKENID"]=> string(23) "53c5406db58374.69023239" ["RESPMSG"]=> string(8) "Approved" } string(23) "53c5406db58374.69023239" string(26) " Rk3gglURw6kecY50rNk9DbQO5"
```

When I try to create IFRAME

```
$iframe = '<iframe src="https://payflowlink.paypal.com?MODE=LIVE&SECURETOKENID='.$mySecureTokenID.'&SECURETOKEN='.$mySecureToken.'" name="hss_iframe" scrolling="no" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>
```

its coming back with:   Error: Merchant Identification Error.

One more think - layout is set to mini or D depend how people call it ;)

Any ideas how to make that to work?

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely related to the iframe not selected and published.

Do the following:
1. www.manager.paypal.com
2. Service Settings
3. Customize
4. Select Layout C Iframe (designed for PayPal advanced)
5. Save and publish

Hope this Helps 8^)